# Подстановка в URL pre-request переменной из csv-файла при прогоне автотестов

Tags: postman

1. Есть csv-файл вида:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. В переменных коллекции определены переменные `id` и `city`
3. в тесте используется id каждого города
4. нужно взять city (название каждого города) и добавить в url pre-request
   `pm.sendRequest({ url: pm.collectionVariables.get('backend_url')+'/api/v1/geocode'+'?q='+ city, method: "GET",`

Вопрос: как прописать city?

Делала, но не помогло:

1. `url: pm.collectionVariables.get('backend_url')+'/api/v1/geocode'+'?q='+pm.collectionVariables.get('city')`
2. `url: pm.collectionVariables.get('backend_url')+'/api/v1/geocode'+'?q='+ pm.iterationData.csvData[currentRowIndex].city`